# Icons on desktop all over the place and reordering is not saved

Tags: icons, desktop, windows-11

For some reason I'm unable to save the locations of the icons on my desktop. I can sort them by f.i. 'Item type' and the get the way I want but when I reboot all icons are all over the place again. Very annoying. It used to work just fine but lately it not working anymore.

Comment: A am assuming that no one has this problem or some have, but don't know a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having some rearrangement being done by Windows 11 and found this solution on Lenovo.com:

> Right-click the Desktop, select View. Make sure Auto Arrange Icons is unchecked. Make sure Align icons to grid is unchecked as well. Reboot and see if the issue is resolved.

(Mostly) works for me! I still occasionally get a few icons near the left of my screen getting shoved over for new ones despite having the "Auto Arrange Icons" unchecked, but it's only occasional now.

At this stage I still consider Windows 11 to be somewhat beta-ware, despite being mostly an improvement on my AMD homemade workstation. The Explorer is slow as molasses sometimes and I still have network sharing and printing errors, otherwise most functions as promised by Microsoft.

Comment: Nope, doesn't do it for me.

Comment: Ok, after boot this morning it did solve it.